# MySQL Where condition with CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

```
WHERE CASE WHEN cksp.status IS NOT NULL THEN ckspc.is_include_in_pipeline = 1 
      ELSE 1=1 
      END
```

Here i want like if cksp.status is not null then condition should be cksp.is_include_in_pipeline = 1 ELSE ignore the where condition

Comment: It seems you are explaining how to do this..Or do you have a problem if so is it syntax or execution? And please include the rest of the query , sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon i need solution for that, the rest query i think not required because i want conditional WHERE clause only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That logic should be similar to:

```
(cksp.status IS NOT NULL and ckspc.is_include_in_pipeline = 1) or cksp.status IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip the case expression, use regular AND/OR instead,

```
WHERE cksp.status IS NULL
   OR ckspc.is_include_in_pipeline = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE ckspc.is_include_in_pipeline = CASE WHEN cksp.status IS NOT NULL THEN  1 
      ELSE 9999999
      END
```

or

```
WHERE ckspc.is_include_in_pipeline =  1 
or ckspc.status IS NOT NULL
```

[DEMO WITH ONLY ONE TABLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94e9fc00bea32124c0167599e2606178)

Comment: And some day another year, someone enters 9999999 as is_include_in_pipeline value in the table. (Such "invalid" values tend to cause trouble once in a while.)